# How to make android camera output act as a webcam?

Tags: android, video-streaming, webcam, live-streaming

From my android application i am sending frames consecutively to PC where i view them on webpage which i am refreshing at the same rate as i am sending them.

But how to treat these frames as input of software like **VLC and skype**. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make use of RTSP protocol, then just use `rtps://ip:port in` VLC. I'm not sure if I know about skype, I guess that's more than just handling frames.

Comment: If it helps someone has done this. It needs some manual setup so maybe it would reveal some clues by you installing it https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dngames.mobilewebcam&hl=en